# Sortablejs-How not to insert a dom element when the onMove function is called

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs2, draggable, sortablejs

I try to add draggable function to the tree item. When I try to drag item A to item B, and I don't let go of the mouse, I notice that the dom element of item A is inserted into itemB.I don't want the dom element to be inserted into another dom element when dragging, I just want an interface to be called when onEnd is made.

```html
<eltree>
  <div class="custom-node"></div>
</el-tree>
```

```js
    rowDrop(dom) {
      const _this = this;
      Sortable.create(tbody, {
        group: {
          name: "shared", // set both lists to same group
          pull: 'clone',
        },
        animation: 150,
        forceFallback: true,
        draggable: '.custom-node',
        onMove(evt, originalEvent) {
        },
        onEnd(evt, originalEvent) {
          console.log('111')
          // some function
        }
      }
    }
```

When I add a `return false` code block in `onMove`, the dom is not inserted. But I found the `onEnd` function is not triggered. I hope it works, I need the final to attribute `to` in the `onEnd` Function

so,my needs are:
1、Don't insert dom item to other item while dragging
2、onEnd function can works, or I can get the final `to` items

```html
<eltree>
  <div class="custom-node"></div>
</el-tree>
```

```
    rowDrop(dom) {
      const _this = this;
      Sortable.create(tbody, {
        group: {
          name: "shared", // set both lists to same group
          pull: 'clone',
        },
        animation: 150,
        forceFallback: true,
        draggable: '.custom-node',
        onMove(evt, originalEvent) {
+          return false
        },
        onEnd(evt, originalEvent) {
          console.log('111')
        }
      }
    }
```

version:
sortablejs ^1.15.0
vue ^2.7.10